# Compile Java project with javac written by Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javac

I have a Java project which is written using Intellij Idea. I want to compile and run it using javac from another machine (which does not have Intellij Idea). Project uses external libs (let's say ./jar_files) and other java files. Whole project has only one public static void main(String[] args) function.

When I compile it via

```
javac -cp "./jar_files/*" Main.java Other.java
```

it comes up with "cannot find symbol ..." errors. Symbols concern external libs I used.

Please help correctly solve the problem.
I hope you can help me.

Comment: Do you use any build tools like Maven or so. ?

Comment: It's a pure java project.

Comment: I found only an advice which says to use -classpath or -cp argument.

Comment: Since you mentioned project uses "external libs" -- Please use gradle/maven etc.  Both has options to create skeleton project ; you can copy your code in correct place and get started .

Comment: Coming to your current problem: You need to ensure "jar_files" is present on other machine - was it the case?

Comment: @MikayelSmbatian java project uses a build tool like Maven, Gradle etc. You should consider usinig one of them

Comment: Initially I was trying to compile and run on the same machine so external libs are in their place.
I'm not allowed to install additional tools.

Comment: Perhaps this post helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/including-all-the-jars-in-a-directory-within-the-java-classpath